# MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i'm making a simple blog app using nodejs + express, i can add first post without a problem but when i try to add second post i got his error `{ MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: restful_blog_app_v2.blogs index: username_1 dup key: { : null }`

this is my schema

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var BlogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    image: String,
    body: String,
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    }
});

BlogSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model("Blog", BlogSchema);
```

this is the user schema

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

this is the create new post route

```
app.post("/blogs", isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    req.body.blog.body = req.sanitize(req.body.blog.body);
    var title = req.body.blog.title;
    var image = req.body.blog.image
    var body = req.body.blog.body;
    var created  = req.body.blog.created;
    var author = {
        id: req.user._id,
        username: req.user.username
    }
    var newPost = {
        title: title,
        image: image,
        body: body,
        created: created,
        author: author
    }
    Blog.create(newPost, function (err, newBlog) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.render("new");
        } else {
            console.log(newBlog);
            res.redirect("/blogs");
        }
    });

});
```

I've tried to dropped the entire database using db.dropDatabase() from the mongo console but the problem still persist, not sure what to do now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by `passport-local-mongoose`, which, according to [its fine manual](https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose#options), makes `username` a unique field by default.

You have added this plugin to `BlogSchema`, which seems like you *initially* had the user data in that schema but moved it to a separate schema (`UserSchema`) and forgot to remove it from the former.

Start by not using it for `BlogSchema`, and you also need to drop the unique index on `username` on the `blogs` collection.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try deleting your Schema and again send the value? I was getting the same issues. I solved with the above idea.